# How to add "rel" attribute in anchor tag in THYMELEAF application to avoid Phishing by Navigating Browser Tabs?

Tags: html, web, thymeleaf, anchor, rel

To avoid **"Reverse Tabnabbing"**, I have added **rel="noopener noreferrer"** in all anchor tags in my Thymeleaf based application which is having **target="_blank"**,  but Thymeleaf is throwing exception as "Element type "a" must be followed by either attribute specifications, **"<>"** or **"/>"**.

Can anybody suggest how to add rel attribute so that Thymeleaf should except it in anchor tags ?
Thanks in advance.

Anchor tag in code :

```
<a href="http://www.something.com/" id="url" title="Visit http://www.something.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Next</a>
```

Comment: That link works fine for me (using Thymeleaf)... are you sure the error isn't somewhere else?  Have you verified the line number in your server logs?

Comment: Yes I verified, Thymeleaf is not allowing multiple rel attributes. I got a solution though. I have added this attribute using jQuery. Something like this- $("a[target=_blank]").attr('rel','noopener'); but still adding both attribute value is showing error.

Comment: Are you trying to add them like this? `rel="noopener" rel="noreferrer"` -- that would cause the error.  Thymeleaf really doesn't have a problem with your code as far as I can tell -- and the error you've posted doesn't seem related to it either.  I still think it's something else in your code that can't be determined from what you posted here.